# Locking on static method

Tags: c#

I am bit confused weather to take lock in a static method which does some calculation, like lets say:

```
public static long ConvertUnit(long number)
    {
        float temp = Math.Abs(number);
        long output = 0;
        temp = (temp / 1024) / 1024;
        output = Convert.ToInt64(temp);
        return output;
    }
```

If this is being called by multiple threads...

Comment: If this doesn't use any external state then no you'll be fine with no locking. If it does then you'll need to consider whether locking will be needed or if it is appropriate.

Comment: I had the confusion that if some other thread comes to the point where output is about to be returned by another thread and set output to zero.then the other thread might return wring value.Please clear my doubt

Comment: If the variables involves are all internal to the method, and the only parameter is that value type, then all state is local to an instance of a method call (it gets given its own stack frame). There isn't any cross over. It's only when you start accessing shared state that you need to start being careful. That method has no shared state so far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

If you can change the method to get `number` as a parameter, then this method will be state-independent and there will be no problems with locking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if `number` cannot be a parameter:

```
private static ConvertToLongLock = new Object();

public static long ConvertToLong()
{
    lock(ConvertToLongLock)
    {
            float temp = Math.Abs(number);
            long output = 0;
            temp = (temp / 1024) / 1024;
            output = Convert.ToInt64(temp);
            return output;
    }
}
```